# Havdalah on a trip

Tags: zemanim, travel, havdalah, contemporary-halacha, motzei-shabbos

If one is on a long trip (that started before Shabbat), and the time for Havdalah at the area they departed is different from the time in their current location, which one do they follow?

(Note the Talmud in [Berakhot 27b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.27b.10) writes one can make Havdalah before Shabbat technically ends). What is the rule? Sources appreciated.

Comment: We generally follow whatever the zeman is in your current location. Why would havdala be any different?

Comment: What sort of trip are you thinking of? One generally doesn't travel on Shabbat. Are you thinking of a boat? But then there is not much difference in terms of time zone between Friday night and Saturday night. Note also that havdala can be done until Tuesday, it should be done when Shabbat ends but there is flexibility to delay at least by a few hours

Comment: But you cannot be a on plane trip during Shabbat, which is why your question doesn't apply in too many circumstances. In any case, as the first comment writes, one uses local time when looking at time for mitzvot.

Comment: You can't really fly during Shabbat, because when you arrive, you would be stuck in the airport, worried of activating anything electric, unable to carry outside the airport, etc. etc. It is really not practical, not to speak of *zilzul Shabbat*, *uvdin d'chol* etc.

Comment: "the principle that Shabbat is a fixed time of 25 hours" there is no such principle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rule for prayers while traveling is one should ([in the words of the OU](https://outorah.org/p/33372/))

> always say the prayer service based on the day and time where you are
> at the moment you are ready to pray.

**As such the person would use the time for havdala at the time of his current location.**

The ideal time for Havdala is Saturday night from the outset of Shabbat. One who missed it can, according to most halachic decisors, still say it until the end of Tuesday since the first three days of the week are linked to the previous Shabbat (but without the blessing on fragrances and light). One should not eat or drink before making Havdala. See [here](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/category/01/01-08/) for more details.

Comment: One can also make havdala in the last hour or so before Shabbat ends.

Comment: Although of course one may not light a candle